# Bootcamp the startup disk cannot be partiitoned

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I cannot install Bootcamp because it gives me an error message of "The startup disk cannot be partitioned".
This is the result of diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1.9 TB     disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data OSXRESERVED             8.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                1.1 TB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            913.9 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 42.2 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.0 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      24.6 KB    disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US... +4.7 GB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Boot Camp              +1.2 GB     disk4
```

and `diskutil cs list`

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common question. Again, here is the commands you need to enter in a Terminal application window.

The next two commands will remove the `disk1s4` partition labeled `BOOTCAMP` and the `disk1s3` partition labeled `OSXRESERVED`

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk1s4
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk1s3
```

The next command return the free space back to the `disk1s2` APFS container partition.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 0
```